# Keep the same height in content within a card bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have two Bootstrap cards and i want to keep the same height, but the description inside `.card-body`

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="card">
        <img class="card-img-top" data-src="holder.js/100px180/" >
        <div class="card-body">
            <p class="card-text">Cost $100</p>
            <p class="card-text">Description: Beautiful item Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatibus </p>
            <button class="btn btn-danger">Buy</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="card">
          <img class="card-img-top" data-src="holder.js/100px180/" >
          <div class="card-body">
              <p class="card-text">Cost $100</p>
              <p class="card-text">Description: Beautiful item Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatibus aspernatur sed alias reiciendis deleniti amet doloribus, adipisci aut, veniam asperiores ipsam nemo vel eius. Tenetur a eius vel impedit officia?</p>
            <button class="btn btn-danger">Buy</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

is pushing down the border of my `.card`, I added some extra padding in the description but it keeps pushing down all my content down. How I can keep the same height in cards keeping my card content in the same height too?

Also i tried adding `.d-flex .align-items-stretch` but the content inside `.card-body` are misaligned

https://codepen.io/motorocool/pen/BadaWee

Edit: I would like to have the same result like this.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/lloYA.jpg

Answer (score 0):

`<div class="card h-100">` on each card or
with css:

```
card {
height:100%;
}
```

If you want the content in the cards to be more consistent, you can check how I did it in jsfiddle

https://codepen.io/todor-markov/pen/jOLOLgP